# Spatial Regularization

Tags: scikit-learn, spatial, regularized

Is there a way to include a spatial regularization penalty to cost functions in scikit-learn for clustering?

More specifically, I am working with neuroscience brain data, where every voxels has a spatially inherited dependency based on their proximity. Using 2-classes gaussian mixture learning, I would like to obtain, for each voxel, a probability score of being labeled as '1' vs '0' (based on 30-ish samples). However this task is pointless if I cannot include a regularization based on neighborhood, as voxels are not completely independents.

Comment: Can you add your attempts / codes ?

Comment: To add some precisions:

- I have n=50 observations (3D MRI scans) in the same space: I then have 100 000 features (voxels) x 50 samples (observations).
- Each voxel has a value between 0 and 100

-Based on a 2-classes classification, I want to obtain a probability map (100 000 voxels x 1)

If I simply use scikit GMM (gaussian mixture models), I won't have any spatial regularization (like 'Total variation', which includes a penalty term based on the resulting image gradients). I wondered if it was possible in a way (if I misinterpreted the method definition).